# Pandas.read_csv: missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am developing a forecasting model in python. The model is supposed to plot a  graph using the given .csv, but I'm getting an error while plotting the graph.

**Code for ploting**

```
from pandas import read_csv
from pandas.core import datetools
from matplotlib import pyplot
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error



def parser(x):
    return datetools('190' + x, '%Y-%m')


series = read_csv('shampoo-sales.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser())
x = series.values
size = int(len(x) * 0.66)
train, test = x[0:size], x[size:len(x)]
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(5, 1, 0))
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
    print('predicted=%f, expected=%f' % (yhat, obs))
error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)
# plot
pyplot.plot(test)
pyplot.plot(predictions, color='red')
pyplot.show()
```

**error**

```
line 13, in <module>
    series = read_csv('shampoo-sales.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser())
TypeError: parser() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

**CSV**

```
"Month","Sales of shampoo over a three year period"
"1-01",266.0
"1-02",145.9
"2-05",191.4
"2-06",287.0
Sales of shampoo over a three year period
```

Answer (score 2):

When you write `read_csv(...., date_parser=parser())`, the `parser` function is called. Since `parser` needs an argument `x`, you get the TypeError.

You need to pass the function, without calling it:

```
series = read_csv(..., date_parser=parser)
```

Comment: using this gave even more error.`line 10, in parser
    return datetools('190' + x, '%Y-%m')
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: well `datetools` is a module, not a function, so I'm not sure what you're hoping to achieve. If the issue is parsing the month column in the csv file, I would ask another question (with only the code related to that issue, see [MCVE]).

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should add x argument just like this

```
series = read_csv('shampoo-sales.csv', header=0, parse_dates=[0], index_col=0, squeeze=True, date_parser=parser(), x=0)
```